# How to add css in aura accordion

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

How to add vertical line in aura  lightning:accordion.

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="slds-card folder ">
        <lightning:accordion  allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true" activeSectionName="AidAllocation">
            <lightning:accordionSection class="folder" name="AidAllocation" label="Aid Allocation">
                <aura:set attribute="body">
                    <div class="blockbody nopadding" id="folderpanel">
                    </div>
                </aura:set>
            </lightning:accordionSection>
        </lightning:accordion>
    </div>
```